# Sqlite Order By Case

Tags: android, sqlite

I am trying to search a list of contacts and present the list in a prioritized order to the user. The order is display_name, phone, email and address. I've reviewed a few examples on Stackoverflow and [sqlite.org](https://www.sqlite.org/lang_select.html#orderby) with no luck.

If the user searches for "john" then all the contacts with "john" in the display_name would appear first, in descending order, followed by contacts that might live in Johnson City, etc.  The search is case-insensitive and limited to 50 rows.

```
    String[] projection = {
        DTab._id.toString(),
        DTab.contact_id.toString(),
        DTab.display_name.toString(),
        DTab.phone.toString(),
        DTab.email.toString(),
        DTab.kv.toString(),
        DTab.address.toString(),
};

String where = ""
    +"("+DTab.display_name+" LIKE ?) OR "
    +"("+DTab.phone+" LIKE ?) OR "
    +"("+DTab.email+" LIKE ?) OR "
    +"("+DTab.address+" LIKE ?)";
String[] args = new String[]{
        "%" + search + "%",
        "%" + search + "%",
        "%" + search + "%",
        "%" + search + "%",
};

String orderBy =
        "CASE "
        +"WHEN "+DTab.display_name+" LIKE ? != '' THEN 1 "
        +"WHEN "+DTab.phone       +" LIKE ? != '' THEN 2 "
        +"WHEN "+DTab.email       +" LIKE ? != '' THEN 3 "
        +"ELSE 4 "
+"END LIMIT 50";

Cursor c = detail_db.query(DETAIL_TABLE, projection, where, args, null, null, orderBy);
```

The sort order is incorrect, as if the order by definition is being ignored.  I get a few records that match display_name followed by records matching an email followed by more display_name records. Insights or suggestions on how to debug it is appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have seven parameters (`?`), but only four values in the `args` array, so the last three parameters have the value `NULL`.

You can use [parameter numbers](http://www.sqlite.org/lang_expr.html#varparam) to reuse parameter values:

```
String where = ""
    +"("+DTab.display_name+" LIKE ?1) OR "
    +"("+DTab.phone       +" LIKE ?2) OR "
    +"("+DTab.email       +" LIKE ?3) OR "
    +"("+DTab.address     +" LIKE ?4)";
String orderBy =
    "CASE "
    +"WHEN "+DTab.display_name+" LIKE ?1 THEN 1 "
    +"WHEN "+DTab.phone       +" LIKE ?2 THEN 2 "
    +"WHEN "+DTab.email       +" LIKE ?3 THEN 3 "
    ...
```

(And as Karakuri said, the `!= ''` did not make sense.)

Comment: Problem solved.  I added three more parameters and removed != '' as Karakuri suggested and it works perfectly.  Me and the CrypSafe app thank you.

Answer (score 1):

Remove the `!= ''` comparisons from your order clause:

```
String orderBy = "CASE WHEN " + DTab.display_name + " LIKE ? THEN 1 "
        + "WHEN " + DTab.phone + " LIKE ? THEN 2 "
        + "WHEN " + DTab.email + " LIKE ? THEN 3 "
        + "ELSE 4 END ASC "
        + "LIMIT 50";
```